# Good treatment of Euler’s formula

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help because I'm  a bit confused about the correct way to treat Euler's formula.

If I ask Wolfram Alpha (WA) about $(i^i)^4$ the answer is $e^{(-2 \pi)}$, therefore, I thought, ok this must be equal to $(e^{i 2  \pi})^i$ but, this is not true, WA says that is equal 1...but, it says that its general form is $e^{-2\pi n}$ but that can not be ever 1...so my head explodes here.

Note: I will appreciate a link to a good explanation about that kind of things.

Thank you

Comment: It's dangerous to write $a^b$ unless either $a$ is a positive real or $b$ is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is obtained from

$$i=e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}+2 k \pi i}$$

then

$$i^i=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}-2k \pi}$$

and

$$(i^i)^4=e^{-2\pi-8k \pi}$$

Comment: You mean $i=e^{\frac{i\pi}2+2k\pi i}$ etc.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Opssss yes of course! I fix that. Thanks

Comment: But, if I do $i=e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}+2 k \pi i}$  then $i^4=e^{2\pi i-8k \pi i}$ and $(i^4)^i=e^{-2\pi+8k \pi}$...but is not true, because $(i^i)^4 != (i^4)^i$

Comment: What I mean is: Is that true: $((e^{(i*(2/pi) + 2*k*pi*i)}) ^i)^4 = ((e^{(i*(2/pi) + 2*k*pi*i)}) ^4)^i$ ?

Comment: @PericoCruel If we consider the multivalued $i^4=e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi\right)}$ then $(i^4)^i=e^{-2\pi-8k \pi}=(i^i)^4$.

Answer (score 2):

The complex exponential does not satisfy $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$.

Of course the question is how you *define* the complex exponential in the first place. In gimusi's answer, it is a multi-valued function. Personally, I prefer to define it as single-valued (which means it is not defined or discontinuous somewhere).

Some information is on Wikipedia at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers

More application-oriented textbooks (such as Wunsch, *Complex Variables with Applications* or Brown-Churchill, *Complex Variables and Applications*) define $a^b$ as multi-valued. More theory-oriented textbooks (Lang, *Complex Analysis* or Stein-Shakarchi, *Complex Analysis*) tend to make $a^b$ single-valued, but only defined on a subset of the complex numbers, and dependent on a choice of a branch of the logarithm.